# Compare two arrays with order matters?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script

```
$a = @(1, 2, 3)
$b = @(2, 3, 1)
if (compare -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b) 
{ 
    echo "Output expected" 
}
```

I wish the script outputs the string because the order of the elements of the two arrays are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. But you could do a:

```
Compare-Object $a $b -SyncWindow 0
```

See some explanations [here](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/compare-object-gotcha/).